# Conceptual Problem regarding an assumption we make while doing Maxima-Minima problems

Tags: calculus

Generally, while solving $Maxima$ $Minima$ problem we come across a function that is under a square root, for instance:

$f(x)=(x^2+x+1)^{0.5}$

In this case, we often tend to minimize or maximize the function under the square root sign and then give the solution to the problem. My question is, why is the assumption valid?

Comment: The square root (for real numbers) is montone increasing: given $x_1\leq x_2$ we know that $\sqrt{x_1}\leq\sqrt{x_2}$.  So if we maximise or minimise the function under the square-root sign we know that we've maximised or minimised the whole function because of the monotone increasing property.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\sqrt{g(x)}$, then $f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$ and $\frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{g(x)}}=0$ if and only if $g'(x)=0$

Of course, we should also look at the possibility of the denominator $\sqrt{g(x)}=0$.